# How to deal with SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. while using Avx2

Tags: c, avx2

## How to deal with SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. while using Avx2 (_mm256_load_pd)(_mm256_store_pd)

## (solved)

### _mm256_load_pd

I've received segmentation fault wile called

```c
_mm256_load_pd
```

usage are as blew

```c
double * Val = malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
__m256d vecv = _mm256_load_pd(&Val[0]);
```

gdb shows

```c
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7fc5017 in _mm256_load_pd (__P=0x555555559370)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:862
862   return *(__m256d *)__P;
(gdb) frame 1
#1  gemv_d_lineProduct_4_avx2 (Val=0x555555559370, indx=0x5555555592f0, 
    Vector_X=0x5555555592c0, Vector_Y=0x555555559340)
    at someThing.c:114
114     __m256d vecv = _mm256_load_pd(&Val[0]);
(gdb)
```

### _mm256_store_pd

while I make Val bigger

```c
double * Val = malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
```

I found *_mm256_load_pd* works rightly but result in

```c
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7fc50e3 in _mm256_store_pd (__A=..., __P=0x555555559390)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:868
868   *(__m256d *)__P = __A;
(gdb) frame 1
#1  gemv_d_lineProduct_4_avx2 (Val=0x5555555593e0, indx=0x555555559310, 
    Vector_X=0x5555555592c0, Vector_Y=0x555555559390)
    at something.c:122
122     _mm256_store_pd(Vector_Y,vecY);
```

### full project

https://github.com/DevilInChina/gemv

```sh
mkdir build;cd build
cmake ..
make
cd ../bin
./line
#then might get some seg fault
```

### Method of solving

change memory allocate function to

```c
void *aligned_alloc (size_t __alignment, size_t __size);
```

first parameter should be 1024 or something else.

Thanks to [igor-r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/759253/igor-r)

Comment: Probably alignment issue? Try using `aligned_alloc()`.

Comment: thank you, i tried aligned_alloc(1024,xx) and get right results

Comment: `Method of solving` Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Intel reference](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-intel-advanced-vector-extensions/intrinsics-for-load-and-store-operations-1/mm256-load-pd.html), `_mm256_load_pd()` requires 32-byte aligned pointer.

Please, use `aligned_alloc()` to allocate a memory chunk having the proper alignment.

Comment: Or use `_mm256_loadu_pd()`, which works on unaligned data.